# Additional Drivers for NVIDA Quadro K620 Required for Ubuntu Installation

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, 15.10

I just purchased a new Dell computer for my work which has a NVIDIA Quadro K620 (The salesman *assured* me that it would work on Ubuntu which it does with installation of additional drivers, I've been able to do this from the terminal).

However, the problem is I can only get this working on 15.10 only and not on lower versions, albiet versions 15.04 and 14.04 are the that are compatible with my programs I need at the workplace.

In an attempt to install from a Flash Drive (USB), The Ubuntu 14.04 it says that the graphics card is not compatible and I need to download drivers and asks to run the initial installation in low graphics.

But when I do run in low graphics the screen turns black and does not proceed.

For 15.04 on boot up it gets to a login screen which I use the User Name and blank password to proceed to an installation page. For this one it stays black and the speaker plays the Ubuntu sound over and over as if it is stuck on a loop.

I was able to install 15.10 with some unexpected text problems but when I installed the additional drivers from the terminal this was fixed and it is working great.

The problem comes with my work programs, they are not compatible and have not been tested for Ubuntu 15.10, and I can't install the programs without GCC header problems.

I have installed these programs on multiple releases of Ubuntu with no problems on other computers, this is the first time it does not work for me.

In my opinion, I think that there are two solutions to this which I need help getting to.

- Install Ubuntu 15.10 then downgrade to 15.04, but the forums I've read on this say to do a fresh install.

The other option (preferred) is

- During the boot from Thumb Drive (USB) if there is a way to get to the graphics drivers via terminal and install them before installing Ubuntu 15.04, or to install Ubuntu via terminal from the Thumb Drive (USB)?

Does anyone know how the correct method to do so and what is the best way to solve this problem?

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the graphics card working without having ubuntu installed.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, install the system, then install drivers.

Comment: Ubuntu is pretty good with backwards compatability. What software doesn't work?

Comment: Rosetta 3.3 or 3.5 protein modeling. I've been in contact with the developers and we think that this is a brand new error. The odd thing is before I received this computer, I installed rosetta with no errors on my laptop which had Ubuntu 15.04 then I upgraded to 15.10 and the program still worked.

I'm getting extension and hpp errors during installation of rosetta for my new computer which went directly to Ubuntu 15.10, since these are new errors and I'm confident I installed correctly from source, I planned to install Ubuntu 15.04 to test whether it was the computer or operating system.

Comment: This worked, thanks. The program I need is up and running and so is ubuntu. It took me a while to figure out how to run in nomodeset but here is the link that worked for me. Thanks again for the suggestion

http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The way to change video drivers in Ubuntu from 14.04 and later is to go to System Settings>Software & Updates>Additional Drivers tab. You will need to be connected to the internet and you will need to allow the utility time to find suitable drivers. But there may be a problem because Ubuntu 14.10 has reached end of life.

Alternatively, Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Then restart the computer and remove the repository after restart as following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

This has worked for me. I hope it helps you too.